# SQL Server database performance insert or update single or multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2014

I am working on a small application which contains around 0.5 million rows in a SQL Server database.

The rows contain the details of products which have unique barcode and needs to be scan before dispatch.

Whenever the user scan the barcode on the product using my application the record is updated with details like scanned by user, scan time and the scan flag is updated in the table.

I have two tables in my database. User details and product details which has the barcode value and user details.

I'm using C# command to execute SQL update command.

The problem is multiple user are accessing the table at once and affecting the performance.

I want advice on whether I should use SQL update or insert the user details into a new table. Which will be faster?

The user sees the scan details like count per hour, scan count of each product. Done and pending count product wise.

Validation like if the same barcode is not being scanned again or invalid barcode.

Please suggest the data structure for better performance.

The Code used for updating:

```
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "update [DispatchData] set [Scan]=@scan,[ScanBy]=@scanBy,[ScanTime]=getdate() where [RunningSequence]=@runSeq";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scan", "Y");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScanBy", username_form);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@runSeq", textBox2.Text);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            listView2.Items.Add(listView1.Items[0].Text);
            listView1.Items[0].Remove();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Table Format

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DispatchData](
[srno] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RefNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[RunningSequence] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FileName] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
[ActNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[imp] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[CustId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CustPhone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CustFax] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CustName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Add1] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[Add2] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[Add3] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[State] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Pincode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[BrCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[BrCat] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ActType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[DispatchMode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[QC] [char](1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DispatchData_QC]  DEFAULT ((0)),
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[misFileName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
[Scan] [char](1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DispatchData_Scan]  DEFAULT ('N'),
[ScanBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ScanTime] [datetime] NULL,
[Dscan] [char](1) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DispatchData_DispatchScan]  DEFAULT ('N'),
[DscanBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[DscanTime] [datetime] NULL,
[manualUpdate] [char](1) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DispatchData_manualUpdate]  DEFAULT ('"N'''),
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_DispatchData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RunningSequence] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: Please show us your data structures as they are now, plus the code that you are using to read/write to the database.

Comment: At least as stated, your question isn't making much sense. If you want to add a new user, use an insert. If you want to update a user, update them. Performance doesn't come into it at that level. That said, if you're having SQL performance problems, you always start by looking into your indexes...

Comment: Is this barcode an alpha-numeric value or just a numeric value ?

Comment: The QR code is alpha-numeric.